# How To Setup and Configure FTP on Windows Server 2008 Securely

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I just recently launched a new "cloud server" with GoGrid and would like to setup and use FTP for deploying web applications and web sites to the server directly.  What is the process of setting up the FTP built into IIS for this server for each site that is hosted, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It is advised to use a protocol that uses encryption for any authentication that utilizes a secret token.  FTP is largely considered obsolete for anything short of anonymous file distribution.

In UNIX, we'd typically use scp/sftp.  There's a Cygwin port for Windows, which I've used in production environments.  I suspect in Windows environments protocols like CIFS are often used for code deployment as well.  However, that would be in a segregated network and not over the Internet.